# Cloud Foundry and Composite UI

Tags: user-interface, microservices, cloud-foundry

We are developing our application which probably is going to consist of about 20 Microservices. We are considering to use Pivotal Cloud Foundry to manage our Microservices and make it easier to have a platform for deployment and health check - amoung others.

About 12 Microservice will render HTML and now we want to know how we can compose all these services to one UI and present it to the client. Does Cloud Foundry a plugin or somehow solves the UI issues for Microservices? Does PCF generates Composite UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Cloud Foundry a plugin or somehow solves the UI issues for Microservices? Does PCF generates Composite UI?

No, the platform does not do this for you. It only handles routing requests to your apps.

> About 12 Microservice will render HTML and now we want to know how we can compose all these services to one UI and present it to the client.

You might look into using a proxy app in front of your microservices. The proxy would just be responsible for presenting a unified front for your clients and combining all the backend services together.

Netflix Zuul/Spring Cloud Zuul or Spring Cloud Gateway might help with this, if you're using Java. I've also see people use Nginx as a reverse proxy to do similar things.

At the end of the day, you're going to need to figure out what works for your particular microservices & clients side apps though. I don't think anyone can give you a definitive answer to your question, at least not without a lot more information.